# Action perform button visible false does not work

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, button

Well, I have this situation, in a program I put a Button whose code is activated with PerformClick (programmatically), that button must be invisible in the interface so I put the value visible=false since the beginning of the program but the action on the event click doesn't perform, but if I put visible = true, the action actually is performed, any ideas of the problem?

```
    private void dataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if(_datosDe == "Insumos")
       {         
                _btnRecargarInsumos.PerformClick();      
       }           
        this.Close();          
    }
```

_btnRecargarInsumos: is the button and is actually performed in another Form.

```
    private void btnRecargarInsumos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {     
        objGeneral.regresaDescripciones(ref dsDescripciones);
        cbACDescripcion.DataSource = dsDescripciones.Tables[0];
        cbACDescripcion.DisplayMember = "Nombre";
        cbACDescripcion.ValueMember = "ID";
        cbACDescripcion.SelectedIndex = -1;
        cbACDescripcion.Text = "";
    }
```

cbACDescripcion: Combobox which will be "reloaded" with the values of the DataSet: dsDescripciones.

The property visible is false since the beginnig of the program, but I also try to set visible=true and just before the method PerformClick() change it, but is the same.

But if I put visible=true since the beginning it works in that way.

Comment: Could you show us some code?

Comment: You should also specify winforms vs wpf (you can use tags to do that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click a button that's not visible or not enabled, nothing happens, even if you click it programmatically. Here's a workaround that works for me, although it's a bit of a hack:

```
_btnRecargarInsumos.SuspendLayout();
_btnRecargarInsumos.Visible = true;
_btnRecargarInsumos.PerformClick();
_btnRecargarInsumos.Visible = false;
_btnRecargarInsumos.ResumeLayout();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put your code in a separate method?
Example:

```
private StuffToDoAtClick()
{
    objGeneral.regresaDescripciones(ref dsDescripciones);
    cbACDescripcion.DataSource = dsDescripciones.Tables[0];
    cbACDescripcion.DisplayMember = "Nombre";
    cbACDescripcion.ValueMember = "ID";
    cbACDescripcion.SelectedIndex = -1;
    cbACDescripcion.Text = "";
}
```

//Your Button.Click() code//

```
private void btnRecargarInsumos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StuffToDoAtClick()
}
```

//Your Datagridview code//

```
private void dataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(_datosDe == "Insumos")
   {         
            StuffToDoAtClick();      
   }           
    this.Close();          
}
```